# Cannot Convert Polylines to Polygons with Curves to JSON

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, database

I am getting this specific error and the following technical article solution does not work, any suggestions?

> The local edits were not synchronized to the server.
>
> Cannot convert polylines or polygons with curves to JSON format
>
> http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/43902/print
>   I got the following error, but the solution from the technical artical did not work - any suggestions?
>
> Cannot convert polylines or polygons with curves to JSON format
>
> Article ID: 43902
>
> Error Message Attempting to synchronize local edits containing
>   true curves from ArcMap to ArcGIS Online displays the following error
>   message: “The local edits were not synchronized to the server. Cannot
>   convert polylines or polygons with curves to JSON format.” 
>   Cause 
>   This is a known limitation. The error occurs if the edits contain true
>   curves; a true curve is a curve that only has two vertices as
>   endpoints. Currently, ArcGIS Online does not support true curves
>   created in the geometry of lines and polygons. Solution or Workaround
>
> 1. In ArcMap, create a local copy of the feature service for editing.
> 2. Export the feature service as a shapefile, and save the shapefile to the desired location.
> 3. Select and delete all features in the local copy of the feature service.
> 4. Copy and paste the features from the shapefile into the local copy.
> 5. Save the edits, and sync the edits to the server. Related Information ArcGIS Help: Making a local copy of a feature class for
>      editing Created: 1/14/2015 Last Modified: 3/3/2015

Comment: Link to help article is broken. Having the same issues, was there any follow up or resolution to this issue?

Comment: @RyNo's no straightforward answer, other than "Closing and reopening ArcMap resolved this issue after also exporting and importing the lines."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing and reopening ArcMap resolved this issue after also exporting and importing the lines.